# owin + oauth + bearer token authentication: full picture

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth, token, owin

I've read articles and seen example projects. I know owin allows to decouple application from web-server specific code, `oauth` allows third party clients to get access to application resources, and `bearer token` - client can get security token by login and password and use it as key for access to application resources.

I know that for simple cookie authentication using owin it's enough `UseCookieAuthentication`. But owin has this extensions: `UseOAuthAuthorizationServer`, `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication`, `UseExternalCookieAuthentication`, `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` and I don't understand the full picture.

1. Could I use `oauth` without `oauth bearer token` (does it make sence)?
2. What are use cases for external cookie?
3. What are use cases for `oauth` (is it required only in case of client and server work in different domains using some api)?
4. What are use cases for `oauth bearer token authentication`?
5. Is it required `oauth` and `bearer token authentication` for web api only and for classic `asp.net mvc applications` it's no need?